# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python

Today is my 3rd day learning Python and despite numerous web searches I can't seem to get past this issue.

The code takes in input on the command line and passes it to the connection script fine and it connects. The problem comes when I try to connect the cursor to the connection object on the line that reads: `cor = con.cursor()`. I get the error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'`. Basically all I'm trying to do is take in parameters for my connection string to connect to the database and then be able to run my query. I request anyone helping me to bear in mind I'm a starter so detailed answers would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
import pyodbc
import getpass
import sys
server_name = input('Enter Server Name: ')
database_name = input('Enter Database Name: ')
uid = input('Enter User ID: ')
password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
querystring = "select top 1 * from SomeTable"
conStr = ('pyodbc.connect'+"('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s')") % (server_name, database_name, uid, password)
con = conStr
cur = con.cursor()   #Generates error on this line
cur.execute(querystring)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a concatenation of two strings, so a string (the parenthesis don't matter):

```
('pyodbc.connect'+"('blah')")
```

And `string % (value, value)` takes the left side string as a printf-style format string and inserts the given values in it. The result again is a string, so your `conStr` is just a string. A string that probably looks like a Python function call, but a string nonetheless.

I think you want to just call `pyodbc.connect()`:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(
      'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % 
      (server_name, database_name, uid, password))
```

Though I'm not sure about the syntax of the strint it expects as argument. At least according to [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows) that looks about fine.

Comment: It was the parenthesis after the last % that was messing up everything. Thanks pikachu it works perfectly. Very grateful.